# Simplest circuit to toggle through 3 colours on RGB LED

Tags: led, digital-logic, low-power

I would like to make a bracelet that has a coin cell battery, a button, some super simple logic, and an RGB LED. I'd like for the user to be able to toggle through the LED being lit green, yellow, red, and off. I know I could do it using a decade counter and maybe even with shift registers, but I'm looking for something simpler than that!
Thanks

Comment: One SOT-23-6 MCU, one RGB LED, and three resistors, plus the CR2032 or similar and the button. And a program, of course. There's probably already a COB for this from China, though. Remember those [gloves with LEDs at the finger tips](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01A316WNE)?

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question. What is the question you want an answer? Most likely such a thing exists and uses a cheap MCU.

Comment: Maybe you have an old saying for this. “ You can whip cream but not from a bull”. ;)

Comment: green, yellow, red does not require an RGB LED ... only a dual red/green LED is required ... a modified  2 bit counter would work

Comment: Design a 3-bit ring counter with a clock of 1Hz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a 2 stage johnson counter. you could build this from a dual flip-flop like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEIKIS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>